# trouble creating launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello Guys ,
I am trying to create a launch file which would execute the command:

rosrun  ardrone_brown ardrone_driver

so here is the launch file:

> > roslaunch ardrone_brown ardronematlab.launch

and here is the corresponding output when I execute the launch file::

```
... logging to /home/karthik/.ros/log/88e084e4-84d4-11e1-a4e9-f04da263aca7/roslaunch-karthik-laptop-6444.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
started roslaunch server http://karthik-laptop:47029/
SUMMARY
========
PARAMETERS
 * /rosversion
 * /rosdistro
NODES
  /
    ardrone_driver (ardrone_brown/ardrone_driver)
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
core service [/rosout] found
process[ardrone_driver-1]: started with pid [6462]
[ardrone_driver-1] process has died [pid 6462, exit code 255].
log files: /home/karthik/.ros/log/88e084e4-84d4-11e1-a4e9-f04da263aca7/ardrone_driver-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

please give your prespective on this

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31724/trouble-creating-launch-file/) by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2012-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like your node exits immediately. To find out why, a few hints:

Check the log file printed at the end of roslaunch for any output related to the shutdown. You can also add output="screen" to see console output, i.e.:

```
<launch>
  <node name="ardrone_driver" pkg="ardrone_brown" type="ardrone_driver"
        output="screen" /> 
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1